# The constraint reference 'string' could not be resolved to a type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

Good morning everybody. I am creating an application on .net 5 it was working fine til last night and now i am testing and i am receiving an error message even without any change on the code so i really don't know why.

That is the error:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: The constraint reference 'string' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.DefaultParameterPolicyFactory.Create(RoutePatternParameterPart parameter, String inlineText)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.ParameterPolicyFactory.Create(RoutePatternParameterPart parameter, RoutePatternParameterPolicyReference reference)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.CreateCandidate(Endpoint endpoint, Int32 score)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.CreateCandidates(IReadOnlyList`1 endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.AddNode(DfaNode node, DfaState[] states, Int32 exitDestination)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.AddNode(DfaNode node, DfaState[] states, Int32 exitDestination)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.<AddNode>g__Transition|26_0(DfaNode next, <>c__DisplayClass26_0& )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.AddNode(DfaNode node, DfaState[] states, Int32 exitDestination)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.AddNode(DfaNode node, DfaState[] states, Int32 exitDestination)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.AddNode(DfaNode node, DfaState[] states, Int32 exitDestination)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.AddNode(DfaNode node, DfaState[] states, Int32 exitDestination)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DataSourceDependentMatcher.CreateMatcher(IReadOnlyList`1 endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.DataSourceDependentCache`1.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DataSourceDependentMatcher..ctor(EndpointDataSource dataSource, Lifetime lifetime, Func`1 matcherBuilderFactory)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherFactory.CreateMatcher(EndpointDataSource dataSource)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.InitializeCoreAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitMatcher|8_0(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task`1 matcherTask)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: text/plain
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: close
Host: localhost:44335
Referer: https://localhost:44335/swagger/index.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
dnt: 1
```

That's my Startup:

```
    using System.Reflection;
using AutoMapper;
using AviationSystem.Api.Configurations;
using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace AviationSystem.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDependencyInjection(Configuration);

            services
                .AddControllers()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(
                      options => { options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; }
                )
                .AddFluentValidation(opt =>
                {
                    opt.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), lifetime: ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
                });

            services.AddAutoMapper();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "AviationSystem.Api", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("Development", x => x
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowCredentials()));

            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("Production", x => x
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowCredentials()));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IMapper mapper)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "AviationSystem.Api v1"));
            }

            mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(env.EnvironmentName);

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it is happening because it was working perfectly til yesterday and now it isn't.

I also have faced with CORS error even with this configurated on my startup as you can see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using your controller something like `[HttpGet("example/{param1:string}/{param2:Guid}")]` then just remove `:string`. change it to `[HttpGet("example/{param1}/{param2:Guid}")]`.

**And for your cors issue:-**

Use below code:-

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200"));
```

Obviously,you have to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors`

Hope it will resolve your issue.

**UPDATE**

it's actually don't cleare where was the main problem is.

if you want to ensure that only alphabetical characters are allowed, you have to perform that check inside your controller once you receive data.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserByNameIdentifier([FromRoute] string nameIdentifier)
```

Comment: I don't use :string on my controllers, only id:Guid but it is not returning error.

Comment: About the CORS: Do i need to change app.UseCors(env.EnvironmentName) that is my Startup to app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200")); ??

Comment: @ThiagoWerneck I actually just give you a demo. if you add ```:string``` in you httpget/post.just remove that.

Comment: @ThiagoWerneck please tell me why you use env.Environment in app.UseCors

Comment: Only one more question: how was it working fine til yesterday? rs i really don't understand. i didn't change anything

Comment: cause i am using this in my services, to choose if it is Production or Development.

Comment: services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("Development", x => x
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowCredentials()));

            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("Production", x => x
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowCredentials()));

Comment: @ThiagoWerneck Okay. so your cors related issue is not here right? if not not gone this issue i will suggest you remove service from your cors related code and just add app.use cors which i posted

Comment: just use service.Addcors().then type my posted answer

Comment: @ThiagoWerneck you understand what i say?

Comment: The problem with CORS i think was solved but the main problem for me is the first error

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: The constraint reference 'string' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'.

Comment: Cause i am not using :string in my controllers

Comment: @ThiagoWerneck can you share your whole project code by using Github? I will check it out.

Comment: @ThiagoWerneck I updated my answer.please check.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but with an [HttpPost] [FromBody] UserRegisterDto registeredUserDto... What if we have an HttpPost?

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
[HttpGet("{nombre:string}",Name = "GetListaCursoporNombre")]
```